# How do I redirect a user (who is already logged in) with the incorrect role to view a page?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, membership-provider, http-get, redirecttoaction

I want to send users who have the incorrect role to another page, however when I use:

```
return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
```

I get the error:

```
Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Web.Mvc.RedirectToRouteResult' to 'System.Web.Mvc.ViewResult'
```

Is this error because I am in an http GET instead of an http POST?

Here is my code as it is:

```
public ViewResult Index()
{
    if (User.IsInRole("Administrator") | User.IsInRole("SuperAdministrator"))
    {
        //Do Admin Things
        return View()
    }
    else
    {
        // Send to a different page
        return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home"); // I want to do this, but it gives me an error
    }
```

How do I redirect a user based on their role in this situation?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change your method to return `ActionResult` instead of `ViewResult`. The latter expects that you will be returning `View()`, whereas the former is a base type that will allow any type of ActionResult object, such as those returned by `RedirectToAction` and `View`

Answer (score 2):

```
public ActionResult Index(){

}
```

instead of

```
public ViewResult Index(){

}
```